# How to achieve this look/unwrap (Swirl texture on tree)

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv

Trying to reproduce the following tree :

[image]

I fail miserably; how to achieve it ? Is it the mesh rotating or the texture ?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are almost there, just unwrap with the *Follow Active Quads* option (select all in *Edit* mode then reselect one of the faces to make this face active) and rotate the UV map in the *UV Editor*:

[image]

Comment: Wow ! Amazing ! Would you be kind and explain what's the 'orange surrounding box' on the left side ?

Comment: I'm in Edit mode  ;)

Comment: Yes but the shape you created on the left (trunk) is actually smaller than the surrounding orange box; what is this ? is this a curve or ? 
Would you mind sharing your blend file ?

Comment: it's because I gave my object a Subdivision Surface, here is the file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3jZQMsOW" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3jZQMsOW/)

Comment: Ohhh ok i didn't know about that modifier; exactly what i was looking for ! Superb Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the mesh is the one rotating, and you should make the actual mesh before texturing. Your texture is good, but maybe make your mesh in the UV Unwrap smaller so that the lines appear bigger.